# How to fail SQL Agent job after CATCH?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

In SQL Server 2012 I have a SQL Agent Job that shows "success" when it goes into the CATCH block, but I want it to show failure. I thought THROW would do this but in the below code when the query performs CATCH, ROLLBACK, and THROW the agent job succeeds.

All I'm trying to do is rollback the previous updates if update2 or update3 fail (pk violation), and in that case let the SQL job show "failure".

Please clue me in...

```sql
BEGIN TRY
    BEGIN TRAN

    UPDATE 1

    UPDATE 2

    UPDATE 3

    COMMIT
END TRY

BEGIN CATCH
    ROLLBACK
    ;THROW
END CATCH
```

Comment: Have you tried [RAISERROR](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/raiserror-transact-sql) yet? e.g.: `RAISERROR('Oh, my heart!', 16, 1);`

Comment: How do you know you're entering the `CATCH` block?

Comment: @AlwaysLearning That works! But I don't understand why THROW didn't?